# Sylius override product Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, xml, symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I'm trying to override the product bundle, i did it successfuly but getting an error when trying to delete a parent entity that have products as childs

here's the mapping file product.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping">

    <mapped-superclass name="Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product" table="sylius_product">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>

        <field name="name" column="name" type="string">
            <gedmo:versioned />
        </field>
        ...
    </mapped-superclass>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

and here's my product.orm.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                                      http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="WeShop\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Product" table="sylius_product">
        <many-to-one field="boutique" target-entity="WeShop\Bundle\BoutiqueBundle\Entity\Boutique" inversed-by="produits">
            <join-column name="boutique_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="true" onDelete="SET NULL" />
        </many-to-one>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

in WeShop\Bundle\BoutiqueBundle\Entity\Boutique i do have

```
<?php
namespace WeShop\Bundle\BoutiqueBundle\Entity;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ProductInterface as ProductInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Boutique
{
    private $produits;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->produits = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getProduits(){
        return $this->produits;
    }

    public function setProduits(ProductInterface $produit){
        $this->produits[] = $produit;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

and in WeShop\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Product i do have this

```
<?php

namespace WeShop\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity;
use WeShop\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model;
use WeShop\Bundle\BoutiqueBundle\Entity\BoutiqueInterface as BoutiqueInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product as BaseProduct;

class Product extends BaseProduct
{
    private $boutique;

    public function getBoutique()
    {
        return $this->boutique;
    }

    public function setBoutique(BoutiqueInterface $boutique = null)
    {
        $this->boutique = $boutique;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Working with the boutique entity (store), i can manipulate it the way i want everything is working, now the problem is when i try to delete it i get

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM weshop_boutique WHERE id = ?' with params [2]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sylius_dev`.`sylius_product`, CONSTRAINT `FK_677B9B74AB677BE6` FOREIGN KEY (`boutique_id`) REFERENCES `weshop_boutique` (`id`))
```

Please note that a boutique (store) can have multiple products in it, but a product can only be child for one boutique (store)

I do have a documents bundle with the same logic and when i try to delete the boutique (knowing that in the table sylius_product there's no rows referencing the boutique {null} ), the documents get deleted

here's my documents orm xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity table="weshop_documents" repository-class="WeShop\Bundle\DocumentsBundle\Entity\DocumentsRepository" name="WeShop\Bundle\DocumentsBundle\Entity\Documents">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
    </id>
    <field name="intitule" type="string" column="intitule" length="255"/>
    <field name="url" type="string" column="url" length="255"/>
    <many-to-one field="boutique" target-entity="WeShop\Bundle\BoutiqueBundle\Entity\Boutique" inversed-by="documents">
      <join-column name="boutique_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false" />
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`` Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sylius_dev`.`sylius_product`, CONSTRAINT `FK_677B9B74AB677BE6` FOREIGN KEY (`boutique_id`) REFERENCES `weshop_boutique` (`id`)) ``

if i understood currectly then this is a solution for this error.

1. you have relationship between `sylius_product` <=> `weshop_boutique`. so when you are creating product, you are passing `id` of `weshop_boutique` to the `sylius_product` table.
2. So when you would like to delete something from `weship_boutique` which has relationship with `sylius_product` then first you have to delete product from  `sylius_product` which has relation with `weship_boutique` after it will works fine.
3. for example

   ```
     =>   you have one field in "weship_boutique" table where "id = 1".
     =>   you have one field in "sylius_product" table where "boutique_id = 1".
     =>   so when you would like to delete field from "weship_boutique" table where
          "id = 1" at the same time "sylius_product" need it because you have 
          foreign key relation between (boutique_id) of table sylius_product 
          and (id) of table "weship_boutique".
   ```

**So first Delete Product (with id of weship_boutique) from sylius_product then try to delete field from weship_boutique.**